# Load node module with SystemJS and Karma in Angular 2

Tags: angular, karma-runner, systemjs

I'm building a web app using Angular 2, SystemJS, and Karma for tests.

I'm trying to load the node module [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) in a test:

```
import {
  it, describe, expect, beforeEach, inject
} from 'angular2/testing';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

describe('Graphs store', () => {
  let graphs;

  beforeEach(inject([Store], (store: Store<any>) => {
    graphs = store.select('graphs');
  }));

  it('works', () => {
    // expect graphs to do something...
  });
});
```

However, my tests fail with the following message:

```
404: /@ngrx/store
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Mac OS X 10.11.3) ERROR
  Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/@ngrx/store
```

I actually had the same problem in dev as well, and it turns out SystemJS did not know where to find `@ngrx/store`. To solve this, I did this:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    src: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  map: { '@ngrx/store' : 'node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js' } // <-- this
});
```

I modified my Karma shim file to do the same. Upon the running the tests a second time, I now get a different error:

```
404: /node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Mac OS X 10.11.3) ERROR
  Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js
```

This means it must be taking the explicit path I gave it into account, but it still cannot find the module. It is the correct path to the module, however, and works when loaded in a browser.

I'm pretty lost on what to do next. Can someone point me in the right direction?

A few things to note:

- Adding the node module to Karma's `files` array is not an option, since its dependencies need to be resolved with SystemJS
- This only happens with node modules for which SystemJS needs custom instructions on where they are located. I can load other modules just fine in my tests without providing a specific location as long SystemJS is able to find it

Here is my Karma configuration:

```
// Set up with the help of
// http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2016/01/testing-angular-2-with-karma-and-jasmine/

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '.',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      // paths loaded by Karma
      {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true},

      // paths loaded via module imports
      {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},

      // paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
      {pattern: 'src/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'src/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // proxied base paths
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      '/src/': '/base/src/'
    },

    port: 9876,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    colors: true,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    // Karma plugins loaded
    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],

    // // Coverage reporter generates the coverage
    // reporters: ['progress', 'dots', 'coverage'],
    //
    // // Source files that you wanna generate coverage for.
    // // Do not include tests or libraries (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
    // preprocessors: {
    //   'src/**/!(*spec).js': ['coverage']
    // },

    // coverageReporter: {
    //   reporters:[
    //     {type: 'json', subdir: '.', file: 'coverage-final.json'}
    //   ]
    // },

    singleRun: true
  })
};
```

And here is my Karma shim:

```
// Tun on full stack traces in errors to help debugging
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

// // Cancel Karma's synchronous start,
// // we will call `__karma__.start()` later, once all the specs are loaded.
__karma__.loaded = function() {};

System.config({
  packages: {
    'base/src': {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      format: 'register',
      map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(onlyAppFiles).reduce(createPathRecords, {})
    }
  },
  // This makes it work in the browser, but not in my tests!
  paths: { '@ngrx/store' : 'node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js' }
});

System.import('angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter')
  .then(function(browser_adapter) { browser_adapter.BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent(); })
  .then(function() { return Promise.all(resolveTestFiles()); })
  .then(function() { __karma__.start(); }, function(error) { __karma__.error(error.stack || error); });

function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
  // creates local module name mapping to global path with karma's fingerprint in path, e.g.:
  // './vg-player/vg-player':
  // '/base/src/vg-player/vg-player.js?f4523daf879cfb7310ef6242682ccf10b2041b3e'
  var pathParts = appPath.split('/');
  var moduleName = './' + pathParts.slice(Math.max(pathParts.length - 2, 1)).join('/');
  moduleName = moduleName.replace(/\.js$/, '');
  pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath];
  return pathsMapping;
}

function onlyAppFiles(filePath) {
  return /\/base\/src\/(?!.*\.spec\.js$).*\.js$/.test(filePath);
}

function onlySpecFiles(path) {
  return /\.spec\.js$/.test(path);
}

function resolveTestFiles() {
  return Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)  // All files served by Karma.
    .filter(onlySpecFiles)
    .map(function(moduleName) {
      // loads all spec files via their global module names (e.g.
      // 'base/src/vg-player/vg-player.spec')
      return System.import(moduleName);
    });
}
```

## Update

There is an example repository with the error [here](https://github.com/dchacke/karma-angular2-error-reproduction). You can see the specific changes that cause the error [here](https://github.com/dchacke/karma-angular2-error-reproduction/commit/8894ac5c275fb7bd021dd35878c1165a15278970). Run `$ npm install` and `$ npm test` to get the error.

Comment: I am facing similar issues when testing from the browser. The paths seems to be the issue here. Any updates on this or was your issue resolved?

Comment: Not resolved yet. Thinking about opening a bounty. I need to fix this.

Comment: could you upload an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a git repo?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Here you go: https://github.com/dchacke/karma-angular2-error-reproduction. The changes I made to cause the error to appear are here: https://github.com/dchacke/karma-angular2-error-reproduction/commit/8894ac5c275fb7bd021dd35878c1165a15278970

Run `npm install` and `npm test` to reproduce the error. It will appear in the terminal and should say something along the lines of "404, cannot find @ngrx/store module".

Comment: it would really help if you didn't remove that repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Including `@ngrx/store` with the rest of your bundles, would resolve 404 error

```
    // for testing in karma.conf.js
    files: [
        // paths loaded by Karma
        {pattern: 'node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js', included: true, watched: true},
    ],
```

But unlike the rest of the bundles that are compiled as System modules, `@ngrx/store` is compiled as commonjs module

```
// 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js'
"format register";
System.register("angular2/src/facade/lang", [], true, function(require, exports, module) {
....

// 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
"format register";
System.register("rxjs/util/root", [], true, function(require, exports, module) {
....

// 'node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js'
....
var Observable_1 = require('rxjs/Observable');
....
```

which causes an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

```
// with {pattern: '~/store.js', indluded: true}
// context.html includes
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js?fb5e807149603c3c2f998c98faf6826c7e301d71"></script>
```

That's why you shouldn't include it:

```
{pattern: 'node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js', included: false, watched: true}
```

This will basically list it in `window.__karma__.files` object, but won't add it as a script in karma's `context.html` - browser won't load and run the code that causes the error. Loading should be handled by SystemJS...

If you run karma tests with `singleRun: false` you can inspect files in Chrome's Devtools > Network. You'll see there a list of loaded files and that's where the last piece of the puzzle is:

In your `karma-test-shim.js` change `System.config.map` to:

```
map: { '@ngrx/store' : '/base/node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js' }
```

> Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0.037 secs / 0.008 secs)

Comment: So did you have to just remove the pattern from the `files` and add the `map` to System.config?

Comment: @mithun_daa You have to keep pattern in `files[]`, or file wouldn't be served when SystemJS tries to load it. You just have to set `include: false` so it's not loaded and executed by the browser, and leave the loading to the SystemJS.

Comment: @Sasxa Ah!! Thanks for clarifying that. I missed the `include:false`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sent a PR with the fix. There might be a better way to do this but this works:

Copy the `store.js` file to the `dist` folder by updating the `package.json`'s `build` script

```
... && cp node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js dist/store.js
```

Update the path in `karma-test.shim.js`

```
paths: { '@ngrx/store' : '/base/dist/store.js' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the PR, but this won't work. It's essentially the same as just moving the package around. It also won't scale if this happens with more packages. I'd like to understand why SystemJS cannot load the module and find a fix for that.

Comment: I am also having issues with pathing, Karma, and SystemJS.  Was there any fix to this?