# @ngrx/store in Angular 2 correct usage

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `ngrx/store` in my `angular2app` project by referencing the files from my `node_modules` folder. My `index` file looks like this

```
<script>
    System.config({
         baseURL: '/',
        paths: {
            'angular2/*': 'node_modules/angular2/*',
            'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'


        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register'
            },

        },
        map: {
            'app':'content/angular2app/app',
            '@ngrx/store':'node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store'
        }
    });

</script>
<script src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/http.js"></script>

<script>
```

The app compiles but on previewing in the browser I get this error shown below. Clearly System.js is ignoring the path I have set explicitly.

[image]

After banging my head several times against the wall , I got a glimmer of hope from the post [Load node module with SystemJS and Karma in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420701/load-node-module-with-systemjs-and-karma-in-angular-2/35515672), but could not get if to work after changing my mapping function.
A plunker from the vendor works, but here they are referencing the file as a javascript file.
Adding this line  `System.import('app/ngrx.js')` in my index file miraculously clears my console but then I get a blank index page with no error and nothing to debug, leaving me in a worse situation. What am I doing wrong here? Why is `System.js` ignoring my path and working miraculously when I do the hard `System.Import(ngrx.js)` import and then denies me a further chance to debug.

Comment: It's not ignoring the path, it's looking for the one you set. Since you didn't add the extension it's not able to find the .js file.

Comment: @Eric Thanks. If I add the node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js extension in my map, the console error remains the same, which is making me inclined to think that this setting is being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the exact path System.js was referencing in the console in my mapping configuration,  I was able to finally get it working. **content**  is a directory in the root folder of my application. It contains the node-modules folder.

```
  <script>
  System.config({
    baseURL: '/',
    paths: {
      'angular2/*': 'node_modules/angular2/*',
      'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register'
      }
    },
    map: {
    'app':'content/angular2app/app',
    'node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store': 'content/node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js'
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would update your mapping for `@ngrx/store`:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    baseURL: '/',
    paths: {
      'angular2/*': 'node_modules/angular2/*',
      'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'app':'content/angular2app/app',
      '@ngrx/store':'node_modules/@ngrx/store/dist/store.js'
    }
  });
</script>
```